# Firestore permissions inconsistent when user registers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have Firebase auth set up with email & password, and after the user creates an account, I create a document for the user in Firestore.

It usually works, but sometimes (maybe 10%) the user is created in Auth but not in firestore, with the error code:

FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions

```
    function registerUser (name, email, password){

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {
            // Registration successful, create firestore document

            db.collection("users").doc(email).set({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                level: maxProblemSet,
                premium: false
            })
            .then(function() {
                //Success
                window.location.replace(myUrl);
            }).catch(function(error){
                //Registered with auth but not stored in database
                alert(error);
            });

        }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Auth Errors here.
            alert(error);
    }); 

    }
```

My security rules for the users collection look like this:

```
match /users/{user} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == user;
}
```

Comment: Using the user's email address as the user id is likely a privacy issue. Please reconsider. The id generated by Firebase would be a better choice. Additionally, I can likely find a character allowed in email addresses that isn't allowed in Firestore keys.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are logged in as a different user?

One possible way to debug this is by running the following in the Javascript console in `myURL` to verify the user identity as seen by Firebase:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser
```

If this works as expected, you could try to print the doc in the console to see if the doc is now visible:

```
db.collection("users").doc(email).get().then(function(doc) { console.log(doc.data()); })
```

Comment: You can also see whether the error goes away using firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged where user != null. If so, you can file a bug at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk.